# Results are wrong when using SUM returns values 3 times higher

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[STOR_totalforadmin]
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- Interfering with SELECT statements.

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- SELECT * FROM tblDraw         

    SELECT tblretailer.ID,Name as retailername, tblretailer.AbcRate,   tblretailer.AbRate, 
           tblretailer.BoxRate, tblretailer.StraightRate,
           sum(isnull(ACount, 0)) as atotal ,
           sum(isnull(BCount, 0)) as Btotal,
           sum(isnull(CCount, 0)) as Ctotal,
           SUM(isnull(Count,0)) as strtotal,
           SUM(isnull(BoxCount,0)) as boxtotal,
           SUM(isnull(ABCount,0))as abtotal,
           SUM(isnull(ACCount,0))as actotal,
           SUM(isnull(BCCount,0)) as bctotal
    FROM tblretailer  FULL JOIN Tbl_ABC abc  ON (abc.RetailerID=tblretailer.ID)
    FULL JOIN TblDraw  Draw ON (Draw.RetailerID=tblretailer.ID)
    FULL JOIN Tbl_ABACBC abbc  ON (abbc.RetailerID=tblretailer.ID) 
    GROUP BY Name, tblretailer.ID, tblretailer.AbcRate, tblretailer.AbRate, tblretailer.BoxRate, tblretailer.StraightRate
END
```

Comment: it return actual  total x 4 times higher value  what to do ?? for example when answer is 4 it returns 16 as value i think problem with join

Comment: thankyou  Vignesh Kumar A  .for correction  code alighnment

Comment: JOINs and aggregation is a bit tricky. You should aggregate in subqueries, before you join.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: sql server 2012

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `FULL JOIN` and do you understand what that is doing? `FULL JOIN` will include all rows from both table even if the ID values don't match.

Comment: i changed it to INNER JOIN

Comment: 1) Please actually ask a question in the question (not just in the title) and add some context/explanation - don't just dump your code and expect it to be fixed. 2) Please add some sample data and expected results so we can see what you are attempting to achieve.

Comment: OK, i'm new to stack overflow, thank you

Comment: @akashkuttan
does the answer help you?
if yes, mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have two table like following:

```
declare @table1 table(Id int, Value int)
declare @table2 table(Id int, Value int)
```

we insert some value like following:

```
insert into @table1(Id, Value) values (1, 10)
insert into @table1(Id, Value) values (2, 20)
insert into @table1(Id, Value) values (3, 30)

insert into @table2(Id, Value) values (1, 10)
insert into @table2(Id, Value) values (1, 20)
insert into @table2(Id, Value) values (2, 30)
```

first we run following query for getting summary:

```
select
        t1.Id,
        SUM(ISNULL(t1.Value, 0)) t1Sum,
        SUM(ISNULL(t2.Value, 0)) t2Sum
from
        @table1 t1
        full join @table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
group by
        t1.Id
```

Result:

```
Id    t1Sum    t2Sum
1     20       30
2     20       30
3     30       0
```

Id 1 in table1 has sum value of 10 but why result is 20?

then we run following query(no summary and group by):

```
select  
        *
from
        @table1 t1 full join @table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Result:

```
Id    Value     Id    Value
1     10        1     10
1     10        1     20
2     20        2     30
3     30        NULL  NULL
```

since we use `full join`, record with `Id = 1` in `@table1` is duplicated because of two record with `Id = 1` in @table2.

Answer (score -1):

Divide your sum by 3 like this:

```
sum(isnull(ACount, 0))/3
```

for all.

Comment: that is fine but i want to know about why it happens.but one more problem is the number of current retailers in this project for test purpose is 3 but in future retailers will increase then how could i manage with /3?? anyway thanks for your valuable time

Comment: consider you have two table table1 and table2 .table1 has id  "1" and after full join with table2 . if table2 have three value of same id then it count three times.